# VSCode and Python extension: Navigating to symbols is very very slow

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am experimenting with VSCode to edit a python program I have.  It is about 3000 lines long.  I have loaded Microsoft's Python extension for VSCode. Most things work well -- linting, etc.

However, when I use F12 to jump to a definition of function or method, it can take 10 or 15 seconds to complete.  Finding the usages of a function is (usually and surprisingly) must faster.  All symbols I am searching for are in this same file.

Do others have this problem?  I don't think it is my machine's limitations, because I've been using VSCode with TypeScript for 6 months, and in that environment, which included 1000s of files, jumping to definitions was always very fast.

Thanks.

Vic

Answer (score 0):

Really this should go onto the github issue tracker for the extension. not here